# System unique id of a function passed as a parameter (javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is probably not possible but maybe some of the stackoverflow geniuses can find a solution :)

W would like to have a function like this:

```
var myCrazyFunc;
myCrazyFunc = function (param1, callback) {
  var funcId;
  // I would like to get an Id of the function passed by callback 
  // which will be different for those two calls in example below
  funcId = getFuncId(callback);
  callback();
};
myCrazyFunc("param1", function () {
  dosomething1;
});
myCrazyFunc("param1", function () {
  dosomething2;
});
```

Please don't ask why I need that :) Simply it would simplify my code if that was possible.

Comment: Something like this http://jsbin.com/OGAXixA/1/edit ?

Comment: You should post this as an answer...

Comment: @patrick thanks. Please post it as an answer, I would like to accept your answer and give my "like"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the function I made:

```
var myCrazyFunc;

var latestID = 0;
var funcToID = {};

function getFuncId(f) {
  if (f in funcToID) {
    return funcToID[f];
  }

  funcToID[f] = ++latestID;

  return latestID;
}

myCrazyFunc = function(param1, callback) {
  var funcId;
  // I would like to get an Id of the function passed by callback 
  // which will be different for those two calls in example below
  funcId = getFuncId(callback);

  console.log(funcId);

  callback();           
};

myCrazyFunc("param1", function() {
  'a';
});

myCrazyFunc("param1", function() {
  'b';
});
```

this example would log:

```
1
2
```

I you run it with the same function code you get the same id, like here:

```
myCrazyFunc("param1", function() {
  'a';
});

myCrazyFunc("param1", function() {
  'a';
});
```

Ouput:

```
1
2
```

I hope that's ok.